# onmouseover inside two div

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to make a multi level menu with JavaScript.
The problem is when I display the first div with the `mousover` event I wish to keep the first div displayed and navigate though it to display the second div.

Can I put a `mouseother` event on nested divs ?
Here is what I wish to do:

```
function show_menu(nom_menu){

document.getElementById('ss_menu_marque').style.display='none';

document.getElementById(nom_menu).style.display='block';
}
                                
function hide_menu(nom_menu){
document.getElementById(nom_menu).style.display='none';
}
                                
    function hide_menus_tous(){
    document.getElementById('ss_menu_marque').style.display='none';
    }
<a href="marque.php" onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque');">
    
<div id="ss_menu_marque" onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque');" 
onmouseout="hide_menu('ss_menu_marque');">
    

<div id="ss_menu_marque2" onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque3');" 
onmouseout="hide_menu('ss_menu_marque');">          
            
</div>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with nested divs:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_menu(nom_menu) {
    document.getElementById(nom_menu).style.display='block';
}

function hide_menu(nom_menu){
    document.getElementById(nom_menu).style.display='none';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ss_menu_marque_root" onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque_1');" onmouseout="hide_menu('ss_menu_marque_1');">
    <a href="marque.php">Menu marque 1</a>
    <div id="ss_menu_marque_1" style="display: none">
        <div onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque_11');" onmouseout="hide_menu('ss_menu_marque_11');">
            Menu marque 11
            <div id="ss_menu_marque_11" style="display: none">
                <div onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque_111');" onmouseout="hide_menu('ss_menu_marque_111');">
                    Menu marque 111
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque_12');" onmouseout="hide_menu('ss_menu_marque_12');">
            Menu marque 12
            <div id="ss_menu_marque_12" style="display: none">
                <div onmouseover="show_menu('ss_menu_marque_121');" onmouseout="hide_menu('ss_menu_marque_121');">
                    Menu marque 121
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can simply show and hide different menu levels as your mouse moves over them, while the higher level menus stay visible.